# cck remote file (image) field - I want to keep the cached copy of the image when the node is deleted

Tags: drupal, caching, cck, filefield, remote-file-inclusion

I use the [Remote File](http://drupal.org/project/remote_file) module for a cck field displaying a remote image. It works with a known issue: images are reloaded on every edit  http://drupal.org/node/395256

And as i do tests with lots of nodes and delete them afterwards, the images cached in filesystem become deleted too. Is there a way to tell filefield(?) not to delete them?

**edit**

Meanwhile found http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources which works very nice on manually created or edited nodes. But there is no way to make filefield fetch the image on assigning the url to the place where it shows up when i let print_r($node) show it to me.

See also my post to this (wont-fix)issue http://drupal.org/node/590756#comment-2774472

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is.

You'd need to create an interface between your node and the file so when you delete the node, the file stays in place. Effectively, you're just deleting the association, not the file.

Perhaps this module saves to the files table and the reference to the file exists already.

You could develop a third party module that stores all your external files and has a GUI or some other interface to select them again for new nodes

Or, you could create a specific content type and save the files as separate nodes. Then you'd use node reference to join them.

Alternatively, the developer of that module says he'll add features if you pay him. However he does not guarantee it from what I can see :)

Comment: I appreciate your attention Rimian but may I say your advice is way too general for me. Of course it could be done by reinventing the wheel or let others do it for money... I still hope for a quick fix as i am yet not familiar enough with module dev to do it and there is much other cool stuff to work on!! :)

Comment: I did give you a specific solution :) using node reference. Hope you get it sorted.